# Using python to automate Autodesk Inventor

Tags: python, python-2.7, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

Is there a way to open and control a solid model in Inventor using python?

My goal to start with a database of dimensions and simulate every configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet is a great place to start:

```
#Open Inventor
invApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Inventor.Application")

#Make inventor visible
invApp.Visible = True

#Set file names of template
Part_FileName_BaseIPT = 'C:\\Base.ipt'

#Open the base model
oPartDoc=invApp.Documents.Open(Part_FileName_BaseIPT)

#Collect parameters
oParams = oPartDoc.ComponentDefinition.Parameters

#Set Angularity        
oParams.Item("Name").Expression = *Value*

#Update document
oPartDoc.Update()

#Save new version
oPartDoc.Save
```